# Hotel WiFi cached wrong password. Now stuck in endless failing loop

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, passwords, login, cache

I am using Mac OS X.

I am at a hotel where a website login prompt pops up when you connect to their open WiFi. I typed the wrong password and saved it on accident. As a result, it no longer prompts for the password but instead times out trying to connect.

Things I've tried so far:

- Completely clearing my cache, passwords, cookies, everything.
- Check my keychain access, no keys stored there.
- Deleted the hotel from my network preferences
- Rebooted my computer.
- Checked my saved passwords in FF, it wasn't there.
- Booted into Windows with parallels, same problem.
- All other browsers same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: When he said Keychain access and parallels, it identified it as MAC OS X for some people, I will edit his answer so it is more clear @ThiagoM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would of saved your password and using a different browser should do the trick. What you are describing though doesn't sound like anything on your end. It sounds like the hotel wifi is rejecting you on their end. I'd talk to the staff.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is the server cache for the hotel has an auto response to save time and bandwidth. You'll have to inject code to cause an reboot of the system.